# How do I convert UISlider value without changing current minimum and maximum slider value

Tags: ios, math

I have 2 sliders, both sliders have a minimum and maximum value set to 0 and 1. In the pic, they simulate changing ramp values at a maximum of 300 total frames combined.

[image]

For the first slider, I get the range of 0-150 frames correctly with

`int selectedFrameCount = 300; 
 int currentSelectedFrameValue = sender.value * (selectedFrameCount/2);`

I'd like to know how to get a range of 150-300 frames with the second slider without changing the minimum and maximum UISlider values because I need those values for a separate calculation.

For a separate function, I'll need to convert that value back to from selected  150-300 value into a float based on the 0-1 value selected.

```
example: 285 = x * (300/2) + 150;
```

Comment: Why are not using this? `sender.value * (selectedFrameCount/2) + (selectedFrameCount/2)`

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it as simple as

```
int currentSelectedFrameValue = (sender == firstSlider ? 0 : selectedFrameCount/2)
    + sender.value * (selectedFrameCount/2);
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You have to imagine your calc as a function (it is, so you haven't to imagine it :D )

`y` is the int you want
`x` is the `sender.vale`

`y(x) = x * (selectedFrame/2)`

If you want to translate your line on `y-axis` by `selectedFrame/2` you just have to add it to as `q` value on linear equation `y(x) = mx + q`

So, the solution is

```
int value = sender.value * (selectedFrame/2) + (selectedFrame/2)
```

To convert the int value into a float value in 0-1 range, use this

`multipliedMaxValue  = selectedFrame`
`multipliedSelectedValue  = value`

```
multipliedMaxValue : 1 = multipliedSelectedValue : x
```

if you want `x`, just do

```
float toRangeValue = (float)multipliedSelectedValue / (float)multipliedMaxValue;
```

Comment: ok thank you. how would you convert it back to a float once you have the value?

Comment: Thank you for the updates. I'm still a little unclear, it looks like "multipliedMaxValue  = selectedFrame multipliedSelectedValue  = value" are both the same value. If I enter frame 285 manually for example, how would I get the result as a float between 0-1? I see that you have it listed here, I'm just now sure how to interpret it correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, my selectedFrame is your selectedFrameCount

Comment: Still not having luck. If I select frame 150, it converts to .5000 instead of 0.0000

float multipliedSelectedValue = textFloat; //150
float multipliedMaxValue = 300;
currentFrameConvertedToFloat = (float)multipliedSelectedValue / (float)multipliedMaxValue;

Comment: Yeah, you have to normalize the value,sorry.  Convert the selected value to a 0-150 range (selectedValue-150). Then divide it for 150.